# bootstrap 3 grid offset takes up horizontal space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3's grid system I am trying to do the following -

```
|button1 button2|       max horizontal space      |button3|
```

or in html terms

```
|button1 button2 float:left|               |button3 float:right|
```

I have created the above using bootstrap's column offset for the middle horizontal space - [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/EVrDX/2/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Join</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Leave</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-2 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Start</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When resizing the offset acts as a block that forces the movement of other items. Is there a way to do this using bootstrap grid that acts in the traditional float behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want but I can suggest you to use `pull-right` for the buttons to be on the right hand side:

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Join</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Leave</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Start</button>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/GpKoFcNvII is the link for a working example.